# Reboot WSL from the console

Tags: reboot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do reboot the current WSL instance from the WSL console?

The usual 'suspects' are not working:

```
reboot
shutdown -r
```

They fail with the messages:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Is there any other way to force WSL to reboot?

Comment: Try the force, Luke: `reboot -f`.  See also my answer below.  (But: I did not try this in WSL1)  And AFAICS: This does only shutdown without reboot at my side.

Answer (score 12):

You would need to do so via Windows `cmd` or `powershell` with;

```
> wsl --shutdown
```

If you have numerous instances and need to shutdown a specific instance or distribution, you can use;

```
> wsl -l -v
```

to see distribution names, the state (whether running or stopped) and the `wsl` version and shut it down with

```
> wsl -t NAME
```

Comment: I know and use all that options... and thare is even a 'hard' way that is kill the windows service that hosts WSL... what I'm seeking (and I think is explicit) is a way to reboot the Kernel from inside WSL,,, to demonstrate a use case... imagine you have a script operating under WSL and you want to reboot from that script...

Answer (score 2):

Following works for me with WSL2 under Windows 11 from within Linux:

```
sudo poweroff -f
```

This powers off the Linux kernel directly without trying to do it via some missing `init` like SystemD.

Note that it may take some time ([at least 8s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#the-8-second-rule), but I also observed 1min) until the instance can be started again.  In the meanwhile, when you try to access the instance, you will observe something like following (this is from German Windows install with Windows Terminal set to German, too):

```
Schwerwiegender Fehler
Error code: Wsl/Service/E_UNEXPECTED

[Verarbeitung des Prozesses mit Code 4294967295 (0xffffffff) beendet]
```

Don't worry.  Just sit and wait a bit longer and try again.

If you are curious:

```
strace poweroff -f
```

shows how that works.  The last lines you see will be something like:

```
sync()                                  = 0
reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_CAD_ON) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
writev(2, [{iov_base="Powering off.", iov_len=13}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2Powering off.
) = 14
reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF) = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

[Verarbeitung des Prozesses mit Code 1 (0x00000001) beendet]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this question was specifically around `reboot` (not `shutdown`).  I made the same mistake in my answer ;-)

Comment: GREAT!!! this really works... I had tryed "poweroff" but gave up with the error messages about no "systemd" present... never thought of trying "-f" anyway,,, THANKS!

Comment: I assumed since it 'grunts' that it can't talk with the deamon 
it will never work,,, 

<<<<
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon: Host is down
>>>>

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Correct!  You are right that one cannot issue a reboot from within WSL directly.  However, as Changes to `/etc/wsl.conf` require WSL to restart and I like to bring up WSL after the host reboots, too, I have an entry in Task Scheduler which starts WSL if it is down (i.E. just run `bash.exe /etc/init.d/cron start` every 5 minutes and let cron start everything else with `@reboot`).  Hence `shutdown -f` actually does a reboot at my side - but now I lack a good solution to really shutdown WSL permanently (; who wants this anyway? ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to understand that, when you are running a Linux distribution in WSL, it's not like running on a physical, or even virtual, machine.  What you are actually in is a container, using similar technologies (namespaces, cgroups, etc.) as Docker or most other container systems.

Attempting to "shut down" a WSL distribution would be like attempting to "shut down" a Docker/Podman/other container. If Ubuntu is running in Docker, you don't shut it down from Ubuntu, but by either:

- Executing a `docker stop` command from outside the container
- Or simply exiting all running processes inside the container

It's the same with WSL.  You can either:

- Stop all running processes in the distribution, exit all interactive shells, and WSL should self-terminate the distribution after 15 seconds.  Note that Docker Desktop will keep any distribution running, however, since its background processes continue to run.
- Forcibly terminate the distribution.  While this is typically done from PowerShell or CMD via `wsl --terminate <distroname>`, it can also be done from *inside* the distribution using:

  ```
  wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
  ```
- Shut down the WSL system entirely with `wsl --shutdown`.  Again, within WSL itself, you must use the full executable name with extension, so `wsl.exe --shutdown`.

Note that any `--terminate` or `--shutdown` will *forcibly* stop the distribution.  This is *not* a graceful termination.  All running processes will end immediately, without being given the opportunity to respond to any normal signals.

For graceful shutdown (copying from my AU answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1353286/1165986)), under recent WSL releases in Windows 11, you *can* now [run Systemd](https://askubuntu.com/a/1431790/1165986).  Services started by Systemd under WSL2 are automatically terminated when *no other processes* (other than those started by Systemd, essentially) are running in Ubuntu.

This shutdown *is* graceful.  WSL2 communicates with Systemd to have it gracefully stop (via normal Systemd signal behavior) any service running under it.

This still isn't necessarily optimal, since you need one additional process running in the background (started "interactively") to keep WSL running in the meantime.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436045/1165986) for a solution on how to do this.  If you use something like `keychain` as I mention there, then you just need to stop that process (`keychain -k all`), exit the shell in Ubuntu, and within 15 or so WSL2 should send the "graceful shutdown" signal to Systemd.

Comment: I have no problem managing WSL from the windows side... I understand WSL2 is inherently a VM... and I reboot Linux in my VMs!!! essentially I understand that the absence of PID#1 control is the essence of the matter,,, and that maybe this will have to pass through a WSL internal addition... the problem is that some Linux scripts I have need to reboot the kernel after making some changes,,, and that's the only annoyance I have to put them to work in WSL,,, meanwhile if somebody knows a hack to do this REBOOT I beg him/her to share it with us...

Comment: @ZEE As far as a reboot hack goes, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090137/11810933) (still off-topic on Stack Overflow, but never got closed).  Hope that works for your use-case!

Comment: that is good info... I'll see what I can do with... thanks!

Comment: @ZEE And apologies -- I didn't re-read your question here closely enough.  I was still answering the "shutdown" question you asked on SO rather than this one, which was clearly about "reboot"  :-/